# Extending blade template from container

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I noticed that If I extend my master page which the **userdashboard.blade.php** the `panel-body` or simple `paragraph` was became clickable and redirects me to home page if I click it. So below here is my master page.

**Master Page**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>@yield('title')</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href= "{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
    @include ('layouts.includes.headeruser')
<div class = "container">
    @include ('templates.alerts')

    @yield ('content') {{-- @yield is always used to get content from a child page into master page. So this page will be master page. --}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my front page this is the first time that I extend the master page.

**welcomeuser**

```
@extends('layouts.userdefault')

@section('title')
    Welcome
@endsection

@section('content')
    Welcome User
@endsection
```

This is the second time that I extend the master page this is the clickable container don't know which the cause.

**userdashboard**

```
@extends('layouts.userdefault')


@section('content')

<div class = "panel panel-default">
<div class = "panel-body">
    <h1>Hello Welcome to Dashboard</h1>
</div>
</div>

@endsection
```

**UserController**

```
public function index()
{
    return view('welcomeuser');
}

public function getDashboard()
{
    return view ('layouts.dashboard.userdashboard');
}
```

**routes**

```
//HOME
Route::get('/', [
'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index',//Specify the name of the controller and the method name.
'as' => 'welcomeuser',
]);

// REDIRECT TO DASHBOARD IF LOGIN IS TRUE
Route::get('/dashboard', 
[
'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\UserController@getDashboard',
'as' => 'layouts.dashboard.userdashboard',
'middleware' => 'auth',
]);
```

Comment: You include a partial.templates.alerts right before your main content and you do not show this partial on here. As far as I can see, everything is fine and pretty simple. I think your partial might not be closing a tag and your panel is between <a> or something.

Comment: What is inside the 'layouts.includes.headeruser' and 'templates.alerts' partials?